# Selecting entitites with the highest value of some attribute

Tags: datomic

Suppose I have one million **article** entities in my backend with an *inst* attribute called **date**, or one million **player** entities with an *int* attribute called **points**. What's a good way to select the 10 latest articles or top-scoring players?

Do I need to fetch the whole millions to the peer and then sort and drop from them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would need to fetch all the data, since there's no index that would help you out here.

I would have created my own "index" and normalized this data. You can have a separate set of N entities where you keep as many as you'd like. You could start with 10, or consider storing 100 to trade some (possibly negligible) speed for more flexibility. This index can be stored on a separate "singleton" entity that you add as part of your schema.

```
 ;; The attribute that stores the index
 {:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
  :db/ident :indexed-articles
  :db/valueType :db.type/ref
  :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/many
  :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}

 ;; The named index entity.
 {:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
  :db/ident :articles-index}
```

You can have a database function that does this. Every time you insert a new entity that you want to "index", call this function.

```
[[:db/add tempid :article/title "Foo]
 [:db/add tempid :article/date ....]
 [:index-article tempid 10]]
```

The implementation of index-article could look like this:

```
 {:db/id #db/id[:db.part/user]
  :db/ident :index-article
  :db/fn #db/fn {:lang "clojure"
                 :params [db article-id idx-size]
                 :code (concat
                        (map
                         (fn [article]
                           [:db/retract
                            (d/entid db :articles-index)
                            :indexed-articles
                            (:db/id article)])
                         (->> (datomic.api/entity db :articles-index)
                              (sort-by (fn [] ... implement me ... ))
                              (drop (dec idx-size))))
                        [[:db/add (d/entid db :articles-index) :indexed-articles article-id]])}}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't actually tested this function, so it probably contains errors :) The general idea is that we remove any "overflow" entities from the set, and add the new one. When idx-size is 10, we want to ensure that only 9 items are in the set, and we add our new item to it.

Now you have an entity you can lookup from index, :articles-index, and the 10 most recent articles can be looked up from the index (all refs are indexed), without causing a full database read.

```
;; "indexed" set of articles.
(d/entity db :articles-index)
```

Comment: I believe AVET index is exactly what you are looking for. Read pete23's answer for further clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Until getting hold of the reverse index [becomes a Datomic feature](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/datomic/YkMn1z0o1Ao/nnPHBxAPnxgJ), you could manually define one.

e.g. for a :db.type/instant, create an additional attribute of type :db.type/long which you would fill with

```
(- (Long/MAX_VALUE) (.getTime date))
```

and the latest 10 articles could be fetched with

```
(take 10 (d/index-range db reverse-attr nil nil))
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking into this and think I have a slightly more elegant answer.

Declare your attribute as indexed with `:db/index true`

```
{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db -1]
 :db/ident :ocelot/number
 :db/valueType :db.type/long
 :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
 :db/doc "An ocelot number"
 :db/index true
 :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}
```

This ensures that the attribute is included in the AVET index.

Then the following gives you access to the "top ten", albeit using the low-level `datoms` call.

```
(take-last 10 (d/datoms (db conn) :avet :ocelot/number))
```

Obviously if you need to do any further filtering ("who are the top ten scorers *in this club* ?") then this approach won't work, but at that point you have a much smaller amount of data in your hand and shouldn't need to worry about the indexing.

I did look extensively at the aggregation functions available from Datalog and am having trouble getting my head around them - and am uncertain that e.g. `max` would use this index rather than a full scan of the data. Similarly the `(index-range ...)` function almost certainly does use this index but requires you to know the start and/or end values.

Comment: Further investigation with large number of ocelots indicates that this solution is rubbish - `take-last` is clearly going through the entire index to get the last few, I was hoping for more optimisation. `index-range` looks much more hopeful in that the retrieval speed is quick, but one needs the start index - which in this case is the 10th highest value... which is the thing we need. More investigation required but I can't help think there has to be something in here...

Comment: How about API index-pull with :reverse true ? It looks good.